# Importing contacts from gmail or yahoo and sending an email to the contacts reitrived Using MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, email

I am working on a project in ASP.NET MVC4 which require that I go through the user's email when provided, retrieve the contact email and send an email invite to all the users.

Can someone help me to with accomplishing this step by step.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of projects on sourceforge, which you can use for importing contacts from yahoo and gmail, for example, [OpenContacts.NET](http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=210092&filesize=178426&filename=OpenContactsNet-1.0.zip)

If you want to write your own code, see [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) and [Yahoo! Address Book API](https://developer.yahoo.com/addressbook/)

Comment: I have downloaded and read OpenContacts.NET which I find pretty easy to understand, but I'm lost on the to integrate it to my project. Can you throw more light on that please?

Comment: The download includes a test project (OpenContactsNet.Test) - just follow it.